# Add autoplay on dynamic video posts

Tags: html, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying get the video in my post's body being autoplayed when the post is opened.

This is what it currerntly looks like:

```
<video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-611-1_html5" width="1080" height="1920" preload="metadata" src="https://jetminister.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/05141345/InVideo___Richard_Branson.mp4?_=1" style="width: 500px; height: 888.889px;"><source type="video/mp4" src="https://jetminister.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/05141345/InVideo___Richard_Branson.mp4?_=1"><a href="https://jetminister.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/05141345/InVideo___Richard_Branson.mp4">https://jetminister.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/05141345/InVideo___Richard_Branson.mp4</a></video>
```

I tried adding the autoplay using the following:

```
    <script>
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wp-video-shortcode").prop('loop', 'loop');
    $(".wp-video-shortcode").prop('muted', true);
    $('.wp-video-shortcode').prop('autoplay', true);
    });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

But it doesnt do anything. What am I doing wrong?

here's a post example where the video should autoplay.
https://jetminister.epic-cars.be/richard-branson/

Thank you

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these attributes to get mute autoplay video :  onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true", playsinline, autoplay, muted, loop

```html
<video width="320" height="240"  onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Autoplay only works if you use the mute attrib.